# How to connect to Unix Domain Socket on client side service knowing only socket file descriptor

Tags: java, unix-socket

My **Service A** communicates with another **Service B** on the same host through *UNIX Domain Socket (UDS)*. The only information I have is a value of socket file descriptor with which the **Service B** is ready to send data through socket to **Service A**. I use 3rd party library **junixsocket** to communicate through **UDS** between services. And my question is how using this library I can connect to the socket on **Service A** side knowing only the socket file descriptor?

I just found how to connect to socket on **Service A** side with socketPath:

`File socketFile = new File("/path/to/your/socket");  AFUNIXSocket sock = AFUNIXSocket.newInstance(); sock.connect(new AFUNIXSocketAddress(socketFile));`

But I need to know how to connect to it with just file descriptor

I’m using openJDK-11, that’s why I have to use 3rd party library for UDS communication

Comment: 'Instantiate communication' means *creating* a socket. There is no prior socket, and therefore no prior file descriptor, to know. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421, sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Since junixsocket 2.4 (although you should use the latest version, currently 2.5.2), we support "casting" `FileDescriptor` to several other objects, such as `Socket`, `InputStream`, etc.

junixsocket will make sure that the "cast" (which isn't a trivial cast since it returns another object) succeeds — as long as the conversion is valid.

Example:

```
FileDescriptor fd = ...;
AFUNIXSocket socket = FileDescriptorCast.using(fd).as(AFUNIXSocket.class);
```

More details here: https://kohlschutter.github.io/junixsocket/filedescriptors.html